# Get all database names from multiple servers

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

We have multiple SQL Servers and most of them are standalone.  I am in need of creating a stored procedure / view that would insert all database names into a table from all servers.

Is there a way to do this via a stored procedure or a view?  I do not have any powershell or .Net experience.

Here's what I have so far.  I just can't figure out how to 'jump' from server to server and add all my results into a real table.

```
CREATE TABLE ##temp 
(
DATABASE_NAME VARCHAR(100),
DATABASE_SIZE INT,
REMARKS VARCHAR(500)
)


INSERT into ##temp
EXEC [sp_databases] 

--doing this to also get ServerName along with the db name.  
--When I insert into a real table, I'll seperate it into two columns plus remove "@_!_@"
update ##temp
set DATABASE_NAME =   (select  @@SERVERNAME ) + '@_!_@ ' + DATABASE_NAME
where DATABASE_NAME not like '%@_!_@%' 

select DATABASE_NAME from ##temp
```

Comment: You can execute queries against multiple servers through the `Registered Servers` window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of thing it's good to have at least one server that has a linked connection to all the servers you need information for. If you do then you can use this little script I just wrote:

```
-- (1) Create global temp table used to store results
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##databases') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##databases;
CREATE TABLE ##databases 
(
  serverDBID   int identity,
  serverName   varchar(100),
  databaseName varchar(100),
  databaseSize decimal(20,6)
);

-- (2) Create and populate table variable used to collect server names
DECLARE @servers TABLE(id int identity, serverName varchar(100));
INSERT @servers(serverName)
SELECT name FROM sys.servers;

-- (3) loop through each DB and collect database names into ##databases
DECLARE @i int = 1, @serverName varchar(100), @db varchar(100), @sql varchar(8000);
WHILE @i <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @servers)
BEGIN
  SELECT @serverName = serverName FROM @servers WHERE id = @i;

  SET @sql = 'INSERT ##databases(serverName, databaseName) SELECT '''+@serverName+
             ''', name FROM master.sys.databases';
  EXEC (@sql);

  SET @i += 1;
END;

-- (4) Collect database sizes
SET @i = 1; -- reset/re-use @i;
WHILE @i <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ##databases)
BEGIN
  SELECT @serverName = serverName, @db = databaseName
  FROM ##databases
  WHERE serverDBID = @i;

  SET @sql = 
  'UPDATE ##databases
   SET databaseSize = 
   (SELECT sum(size)/128. FROM ['+@serverName+'].['+@db+'].sys.database_files)
   WHERE serverDBID = '+CAST(@i AS varchar(4))+';'

  BEGIN TRY 
    EXEC (@sql);
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'There was an error getting dbsize info for '+@serverName+' > '+@db;
  END CATCH;

  SET @i += 1;
END;

-- Final Output
SELECT * FROM ##databases;
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server Management Studio allows you to execute a [query against multiple servers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964743.aspx) using the [Registered Servers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188231.aspx) feature. This was added in [SQL Server 2008 as this tutorial shows](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2008/10/sql-server-2008-management-studio-group-execute/) so you shouldn't worry about compatibility.

Running multi-server queries is easy:

1. From the `View` menu, select `Registered Servers. This will open a new window similar to the Object Explorer that displays the objects of a single server.
2. Add connections for all your servers connection details in the `Local Server Groups` folder
3. Right-click on the Local Server Groups folder and select `New Query`. The query you enter here will run an all registered servers.
4. To find all databases run `select * from sys.databases` or just `sp_databases`

SSMS will collect the results from all servers and display them in a grid. If you want the results to go to a single server's table though, you'll have to add the target server as a linked server to all others and use a four-part name to target the target table, eg `INSERT INTO myManagementServer.MyDb.dbo.ThatTable...`

SQL Server has even more powerful features for managing multiple servers. You can administer multiple servers through a [Central Management Server](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2008/08/sql-server-2008s-new-central-management-server/) and apply settings to multiple servers through policies. That feature was also added in 2008.

In SQL Server 2008 R2 the [SQL Server Utility](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2008/introducing-sql-server-utility) was added which goes even farther and collects diagnostics, metrics, performance data from multiple servers and stores it in a management warehouse for reporting. Imagine being able to see eg storage and query performance for multiple servers, or free space trends for the last X months.

The drawbacks are that historical data needs space. Collecting it also requires adding some stored procedures to all monitored servers, although this is done automatically.